# Confluent server went down

Tags: confluent-platform

I am a starter in Confluent and Kafka.

When I am using the Confluent Platform on the slave node server(distributed mode but only on one server), the Confluent Server(only the server, the kafka is working properly) went down from time to time. Cause I am new to that, so I make mistakes when creating the sources and sinks, does that have anything to do with the break-down?

Here is my config:

```
# Sample configuration for a distributed Kafka Connect worker that uses Avro serialization and
# integrates the the Schema Registry. This sample configuration assumes a local installation of
# Confluent Platform with all services running on their default ports.

# Bootstrap Kafka servers. If multiple servers are specified, they should be comma-separated.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# The group ID is a unique identifier for the set of workers that form a single Kafka Connect
# cluster
group.id=connect-cluster

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data.
# Every Connect user will need to configure these based on the format they want their data in
# when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:18081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:18081

# The internal converter used for offsets and config data is configurable and must be specified,
# but most users will always want to use the built-in default. Offset and config data is never
# visible outside of Connect in this format.
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

# Kafka topic where connector configuration will be persisted. You should create this topic with a
# single partition and high replication factor (e.g. 3)
config.storage.topic=connect-configs

# Kafka topic where connector offset data will be persisted. You should create this topic with many
# partitions (e.g. 25) and high replication factor (e.g. 3)
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets

# Kafka topic where connector status data will be persisted. You should create this topic with many
# partitions (e.g. 25) and high replication factor (e.g. 3)
status.storage.topic=connect-statuses

# Confuent Control Center Integration -- uncomment these lines to enable Kafka client interceptors
# that will report audit data that can be displayed and analyzed in Confluent Control Center
producer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
consumer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor
```

So curious about that, cause Confluent Platform is a well designed project and Supported by a lot of experts, more importantly it is commercial.

Feiran

Comment: Not sure what you mean be "slave node server" or "Confluent Server"... What "source" or "sinks" are you talking about? The config shows Kafka Connect though -- in Connect going down?

Comment: the cluster has one master and two slaves, I installed the Confluent on a slave. Source is jdbc connector and the sink is hdfs connector.

Comment: the connect is not down, only the control center is down, I can't add source and sink through the web

Comment: @Feiran You only provided the Connect configuration file, but you're asking about Control Center. If you have the Control Center config & a log file showing how it failed, someone might have a better chance of determining the issue.